# Maven: m2eclipse: Disable Workspace Resolution Causes Artifact Missing

Tags: eclipse, maven, workspace, m2e

I have project A which depends on projects B and C in my Eclipse workspace.

Sometimes I want A to run using the artifacts B and C from the repository rather the versions in the workspace.  Therefore, I select A, and then select 'Maven-> Disable Workspace Resolution' so that A would use the versions from the repository.

However, as soon as I take the above action, I get the error messages "Missing artifact B" and "Missing artifact C" in the pom file of project A.

I've tried to clean up the project, I've select 'Maven | Update' with the option 'Force update of jars/releases' checked. Non of these have resolved the problem.

Am I using 'Maven-> Disable Workspace Resolution' incorrectly?

---

Additional Info:  The exact versions of those projects are in repository. In fact, if I close projects B and C in the workspace, project A happily uses repository versions of B and C.

Comment: Why the [tag:subclipse] tag and Subclipse in the title: why do you think Subclipse is involved?

Comment: Because "Disable workspace resolution" is a feature of Subclips plugin.

Comment: It isn't-- it is a feature of the m2eclipse (Maven) plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I always mix up the names of these 2 plugin.  Corrected the title and tags.

Comment: I have also faced this issue because of m2e plugin for eclipse. eclipse is hostile to many plugin and this is one of it. May be the upgrading eclipse can solve your issue like way it got resolved for me. Try command line mvn too to build and install, it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to have the projects B and C installed in your local m2 repository with the exact versions as they are referenced in the pom.xml of project A.

Comment: I know.  The exact versions of those projects are in repository.  In fact, if I close projects B and C in the workspace, project A happily uses repository versions of B and C.

Comment: In our environment m2eclipse behavior is the same as mentioned by user2295633

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue (if not a bug) after all: [troubleshooting-missing-artifact](http://www.mograblog.com/2013/01/troubleshooting-missing-artifact-in-eclipse-maven-repository.html)

I have a similar setup (web project A depends on jar project B) so I try to reproduce as it is described in the above link:

> projectA and projectB.
>   Both project use Maven.
>   projectA should have a dependency on projectB.
>   Set up an Eclipse workspace with both projects.
>   Right click on projectA and go to "Maven ==> Disable Workspace Resolution"
>   Clean / Update / Rebuild projects.
>   You get a "Missing Artifact" error message.

In my case this is not happening. Only If I then go to my local repository and delete by hand the directory that contains my project and then do a maven update.

I don't know if it is the eclipse version but I am working on: 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why zlinks cited the directions to reproduce the error, but not the actual solution (that worked for me at least). So ...

> On the repository view ( Window ==> View ==> Other ==> Maven
>   Repository ) you should focus on the unsynched repository ( mine was
>   the local repository ) and then right click and choose "reindex"

That did it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solve this by close and open project B and C.

> right click project B and C -> 'Close project' -> maven update project
>   A -> open project B and C