# Eclipse mars is too slow.. Always busy in scanning classpath

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I am using eclipse mars 4.5. Problem is, it always busy with scanning class path that actually makes eclipse too slow to work on. I am working on the multimodule OSGI projects, so there are around 30 projects in the workspace and eclipse every time starts scanning classpath for all projects.

can anybody help to optimize the eclipse and stopping auto  class path scan for each project.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine the vaadin designer scanned each projects of my workspace (in my case about 100 bundles), and this took very long (eclipse Mars.2 and Neon)

Hint: open visualvm - connect to eclipse pid; create a thread dump and analyze the worker threads of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and the only things I do are:

1. Maven plugin:

   If you use the maven plugin, on each project, choose the Maven option `Disable Workspace Resolution` the other project will not refers anymore those in the workspace.

Apparently this is a known bug and you can find some more solution like rebuilding the maven indexes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20100641/628006).

2. Maven in command line:

   Another option I choose is to use the maven on command line (It's not perfect but in the environment I work in it is the best solution) and use the option "Offline" in the maven preferences. This is due to proxy which is not working from Eclipse but work from command line (my setup).

Personally I use both option but this is due to a very strict proxy which is not friendly; I think this is a good setup for OSGI as trying to resolve all dependencies could be very long.

Another point: try to see if you have circular dependencies, it can happens very quickly in OSGI environment and I guess that can also make the compiler to be mad.