# How can I make Eclipse reference to the latest version in remote repo instead of current version in workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use maven version range for one of the dependency in project A,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>[0.2,)</version>
</dependency>
```

In Eclipse I also have project com.test.B in the same Workspace as project A.
I want to get version 0.2.5 which is the latest version in my remote repo,
but in Eclipse it reference to 0.2.6-SNAPSHOT which is my current development version and I haven't upload to remote repo yet, so I got

> 'Maven dependencies' references non existing library

error in Eclipse. How can I make Eclipse reference to the latest version in remote repo instead of current version in workspace? I tried Disable workspace resolution, didn't work. delete project B from the workspace do the trick, but I need project B.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407055/how-do-i-stop-maven-version-ranges-from-using-snapshots

Comment: @FranMontero hey Fran, but in this case, there is no 0.2.6-SNAPSHOT in remote repo or my local ~/.m2 folder

Comment: I found out this is same problem as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100641/maven-m2eclipse-disable-workspace-resolution-causes-artifact-missing/49357084#49357084   and close project B solve this without modify pom or delete the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that this can be resolved @Sophia!

- You could either go to your Project, right click and say 'Maven' -> 'Update Project'
- If the above approach doesn't help, you can clean your project. Right click on your `pom.xml` Run as -> Maven build (with the goals as `clean install`).

When u fire multiple commands in single line..say mvn versions:resolve-ranges clean install...it will fetch SNAPSHOT when do release build.

Try with separate execution of commands.

Firstly run `mvn versions:resolve-ranges` and then run `clean install`

Hope these steps solve your problem!

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried both approach, but still have same error.

Comment: I clean install both projects, still ref to 0.2.6-SNAPSHOT

Comment: but this approach is actually change version range to explicit version